# i want to make array [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11] to array[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,0,1,1] using only this algorithm

Tags: php, arrays

I try to insert a new array into an array

I tried to cut it using modular and reverse it

```
<?php
literal(12);
function literal($sum){
$n;
for($i=0;$i<$sum;$i++){
 $n[] = $i+1;
 echo $n[$i];
 $length = strlen($n[$i]);//count length reset every loop
 $keeper = $n[$i]; //store on new variable reset every loop
 for($m=0;$m<$length;$m++){
   if($keeper>=10){//just skip if below ten
     $newstore[$m] = $keeper%(10^($length-($m+1)));
     $keeper = floor($keeper/10);
   }else {
     $newstore[$m] = $keeper;// this value to keep array and reset it, then keep it again
   }
  }
  $newstored = array_reverse($newstore);//reverse it and reset again
  for($a=0;$a<count($newstored);$a++){
      $fixed[] = $newstored[$a];
  }
}
echo nl2br("\n".count($n)."\n");
for($i=0;$i<count($fixed);$i++){
    echo $fixed[$i];
}
echo nl2br("\n".count($fixed));
}
?>
```

result that i want was `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,0,1,1,1,2]`
actual result that i got `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1]`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ar = range(1,12);
// split each item
$ar = array_map('str_split', $ar);
// flatten array
$ar = array_merge(...$ar);
print_r($ar);
```

EDIT

To make you code working just change to

```
 $newstore[$m] = $keeper%10;
```

Or if you want to divide by powers of ten, don't change initial value

Comment: Than just change to `$newstore[$m] = $keeper%10;`

Comment: i think the output was different from mine. cause i want to multiply it too.

Comment: @GigaPudding Are you sure?

Comment: i need to keep `$newstore[$m] = $keeper%(10^($length-($m+1)));` cause this input range up to 10k

Comment: can we just focus on my code please, pretty sure i did right on my code there, it just something wrong there

Comment: just change to $newstore[$m] = $keeper%10; - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dfcb0b823ea20295dbe26131c17125ad633a8922

Comment: is `10^(length-($m+1))` same like `10^(2-1)` which is `10`, I need to keep `(10^($length-($m+1)))` cause the `$length` can be `1-5`

Comment: oh i got it, you right. just change to $keeper%10, no need to mod with 100 or 1000.

Answer (score 2):

To get your desired result, you could use a [range](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) from 1-12 and use [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to turn that into a string.

Then use [str_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) to create the resulting array.

```
$res = str_split(implode(range(1,12)));
print_r($res);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
    [9] => 1
    [10] => 0
    [11] => 1
    [12] => 1
    [13] => 1
    [14] => 2
)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/UIM0q)

Comment: @Giga This is a superior answer. Use this one; it doesn't get cleaner than this.

Comment: I think the title already make it clear. I only need to use this algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Another way ith simple `foreach()` and `str_split()`,

```
<?php
$array = range(1,20);
$result = [];
foreach($array as $num){
    if(strlen($num) < 2){
        $result[] = $num;
    }else{
        $parts = str_split($num);
        $result = array_merge($result,$parts);
    }
}
print_r($result);
?>
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/QXRrW

Comment: this one simple and correct, but i need another answer. can you correct me on my code. what did i do wrong?